# Using HTML code references in Froala text editor

Tags: html, wysiwyg, froala

I am using Froala Texteditor. The text that is inserted inside the textarea-field can contain actual HTML-code references that shall be treated as text and not as HTML-code/elements.

When I enter an HTML tag inside the textarea (such as <div>) it will ultimately be removed by the Froala texteditor since it treats it as actual HTML-code not as text.

The feature I need is the same as right here inside the stackoverflow wysiwyg - here the HTML-Elements are treated as text when indenting with 4 whitespaces (when block) or when using HTML-entites (for inline)

Using HTML-entites in Froala did not yield the result though.

Thanks for any hint

Comment: Hi. I cannot reproduce. Can you please provide an example with reproducing steps? A jsfiddle could be helpful too.

If I type '<div></div>' in the editor it will be treated as text and it will not be  removed.